# SE BOOTLOADER v1.6 Problem (FAILED:phone is already unlocked)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications, rooting, 4.2-jelly-bean, bootloader-lock

I tried to unlock my bootloader with SE BOOTLOADER TOOL but get the message:

> (bootloader) Unlock phone requested FAILED (remote: Phone is already
>   unlocked!) finished. total time: 0.002s

What should I do now to fix it?

Comment: Do you have 4.0 or 4.2? You've tagged both.

Comment: Could it be the error message is correct, and your device is already unlocked? Maybe it's not a problem at all.